# PHP get array of words from txt file

Tags: php

I have a text file with spam words. I want to have an array filled with those words.
I've tried doing:

```
$fp = @fopen("../files/spam.txt",'rb');
$words = fgetcsv($fp,100,"\n");
```

but it doesn't work (words only has the first letter of the txt file in it first cell).

do you how to do this?

EDIT:
the .txt file looks like this:

```
yahoo
google
msn
blah
blah
```

EDIT:
**I DONT KNOW WHAT IS A CSV FILE! THIS IS A TEXT FILE! I JUST GIVE AN EXAMPLE.**

please could some1 help me it looks really easy, i just dont understand.

Comment: your text file is in csv format, or one word every line?

Comment: There are different ways to do this depending on how your text file is formatted.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the spam.txt file

Comment: it's a word in every line, like this:
google
yahoo
spam
(and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a CSV file. CSV stands for comma separated values. You have no commas!

```
$spam_words = file('../files/spam.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: thanks, i just didn't get which one i should use, besides everyone here recommends something else it's really confusing "CSV! CSV! it's CSV!" - god ppl can't you see i'm a newbie??

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
$words = file('./files/spam.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$artic = array();  //create a array 
$directory = "/var/www/application/store/";  //define path
$files1 = scandir($directory); //scan the directory
$c = count($files1); //count the files the directory

print $c;  //print it

    for($i = 2; $i < $c; $i++) {
    print "<br />" . $files1[$i];
    $f = $directory . $files1[$i];
    print $f . "<br />";
    $h = fopen($f, 'r') or die("cannot open a file!!". $f); 
    $line1 = fgets($h); 
    list($id, $idval) = explode("\t\t", $line1);
    print "$id";
  }
```

Comment: I came across the question looking for something and noticed your answer at the same time. There is either an extra or missing quote for `"$line1)`

Comment: Thank you Fred ii, I have made the correction. there one of the double quote was extra i have removed now.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the string you read from the file into an array?

[split() function definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php).

```
$string = "Niagara Becks Corn";
$array = split(" ", $string);
# ["Niagara", "Becks", "Corn"]
```

Comment: you can also use explode function

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'file' function to read a PHP file from the disk into an array. See the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: OP doesn't know what a csv is apparently =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$file = file_get_contents('spam.txt');
$file_words = explode(" ", $file);
$file_count = count($file_words);

for ($i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++){
    echo $file_words[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Your spam.txt file should look like this:

> yahoo msn google